# Percentage-based flex elements "jump" when transitioning the gap value

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with multiple flex elements inside, separated by a `gap`. These elements wrap within the container, and have a percentage-based size dictating how many can appear in a single row (ie, 4 per row = 25%).

Now, because the percentage-based size doesnt take into account the gap size, we must use a formula to determine the size of the elements, taking into account the gap we need (taken from [here](https://wiryawanadipa.com/blog/calculate-percentage-width-of-flex-items-when-using-gap/)):

`calc((100% / var(--flex-items)) - (((var(--flex-items) - 1) / var(--flex-items)) * var(--flex-gap)));`

This works fine and well, an is easily adaptable for different amount of flex objects per row. But the issue comes in when changing the value of the `gap`, while transitioning it.

While the appearance before and after the transition appear as they should, during the transition, the calculation is for some reason, not being made correctly, and so one more item wraps than should, until settling into how it should look after the appearance. This only happens when DECREASING the value of `gap` — it animates as expected when increasing the `gap`

What is happening the during the animation between the 2 values that is causing the width calculation / gap value to not be in sync?

### Codepen

[Here](https://codepen.io/GtwoK/pen/ZEZKzbM)

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(".flexbox").toggleClass("bigger");
} );
```

```css
:root {
    --flex-gap: 1rem;
}

.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: var(--flex-gap);
    justify-content: center;
    transition: gap 0.5s;
}

.flexbox.bigger {
  --flex-gap: 3rem;
}

.flex-items {
    --flex-items: 4;
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
    display: flex;
    background: red;
    flex: 1 1 calc((100% / var(--flex-items)) - (((var(--flex-items) - 1) / var(--flex-items)) * var(--flex-gap)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your issue is due to the `.flex-title` element occupying two (or more) characters. In that case there's just not enough space to make them all fit when going small. You could scale down the `font-size` too to prevent this.

Comment: Sorry, issue is not related to the contents of the children (my real code does not have any, I added them to this demo for legibility reasons). I've removed them & simplified the example here to just the essentials, and the issue still occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a transition to the `flex-basis` on the flex items as well.

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(".flexbox").toggleClass("bigger");
} );
```

```css
:root {
    --flex-gap: 1rem;
}

.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: var(--flex-gap);
    justify-content: center;
    transition: gap 0.5s;
}

.flexbox.bigger {
  --flex-gap: 3rem;
}

.flex-items {
    --flex-items: 4;
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
    display: flex;
    background: red;
    flex: 1 1 calc((100% / var(--flex-items)) - (((var(--flex-items) - 1) / var(--flex-items)) * var(--flex-gap)));
    transition: flex-basis 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
      <div class="flex-items"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. Whats the mechanism behind this? I'd thought about transitioning the flex-basis until I realized that I wasn't actually changing the flex-basis anywhere, so there would be nothing to transition between. Yet it works, somehow?

Comment: @GtwoK the flex items are inheriting the value of the gap variable so there is no transition happening at the flex items, their flex-basis will have an abrupt change when you update the values. You need to add a transition to it so it changes the same way as the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies with a sort of edge effect with the widths being calculated, there may be some point at which part CSS pixels don't quite fit within the actual screen pixels (tho' I'm not certain).

However, switching to grid overcomes the problem.

```js
$("body").on("click", function() {
  $(".flexbox").toggleClass("bigger");
});
```

```css
:root {
  --flex-gap: 1rem;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--flex-gap);
  justify-content: center;
  transition: gap 0.5s;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--items), 1fr);
  --items: 4;
}

.flexbox.bigger {
  --flex-gap: 3rem;
}

.flex-items {
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That definitely fixes the issue with animating the gaps, but does introduce a new issue in that the children elements are no longer center aligned — my use case doesnt necessarily have enough children to fill each row

Comment: Ah, I hadn’t spotted that as a requirement, perhaps highlight it as a requirement with an odd number of elements?